# Getting Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL:

Tags: node.js, async-await, http-status-code-404, koa, koa.js

I am making a request to endpoint written in koa.js and I am new to this framework.
API return 404 response.

Route file looks like below:

```
const collabRepo = require("../repo/collab/collab-repo")
const notificationRepo = require("../repo/collab/notification-repo")
const rest = require("restling")
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const CONFIG = require("config")
const SECRET = CONFIG.get("auth.jwt.secret")
const JWT_COOKIE_NAME = CONFIG.get("auth.jwt.cookie.name")
const TOKENTIME = CONFIG.get("auth.jwt.ttl")
const FEED_API_BASE = CONFIG.get("urls.activityFeedApi")
const FEED_API_VERSION = "v1"
const FEED_API = FEED_API_BASE + "/" + FEED_API_VERSION
const logger = require("winston")
const { jwtAuth } = require("../auth")

const PROTECTED_ROUTES = [
    "/collab/follow",
    "/collab/unfollow",
    "/collab/follower/list",
    "/collab/follower/public/list",
    "/collab/following/list",
    "/collab/following/public/list",
    "/collab/following/count",
    "/collab/following",
    "/collab/notify",
    "/collab/discover/people",
    "/collab/discover/expression"
]

async function followFeed(toFollowId, userObject, follow) {
    const args = {
        data: {
            follow: {
                class: "user",
                id: toFollowId
            }
        },
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Cookie": JWT_COOKIE_NAME + "=" + jwt.sign(userObject, SECRET, {
                expiresIn: TOKENTIME
            })
        }
    }
    if (follow) {
        return rest.post(FEED_API + '/follow', args)
    }
    return rest.post(FEED_API + '/unfollow', args)
}
```

when I log rest.post(FEED_API + '/follow', args) I get:

> Promise {   _bitField: 0,   _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
>   _rejectionHandler0: undefined,   _progressHandler0: undefined,   _promise0: undefined,   _receiver0: undefined,   _settledValue: undefined } Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot POST
>   http://localhost/activity-feed/api/v1/follow
>       at Request. (\node_modules\restling\restling.js:26:21)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
>       at Request._fireSuccess (\node_modules\restler\lib\restler.js:223:12)
>       at \node_modules\restler\lib\restler.js:161:20
>       at IncomingMessage.auto (\node_modules\restler\lib\restler.js:402:7)
>       at Request._encode (\node_modules\restler\lib\restler.js:198:29)
>       at \node_modules\restler\lib\restler.js:157:16
>       at Request._decode (\node_modules\restler\lib\restler.js:173:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (\node_modules\restler\lib\restler.js:150:14)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1106:12)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)

```
module.exports = (router) => {
    // Protect the marked routes
    PROTECTED_ROUTES.forEach(url => {
        router.use(url, jwtAuth)
    })
    // router.use("/collab", jwtAuth)

    router.post("/collab/follow", async function (ctx) {
        try {
            const resp = await followFeed(ctx.request.body.followee_id, ctx.state.user, true)
            return collabRepo.follow(ctx.state.user.id, ctx.request.body.followee_type, ctx.request.body.followee_id)
                .then(data => {
                    ctx.body = {
                        data: data,
                        feed_data: resp.data
                    }
                })
        } catch (error) {
            return error
        }
    }),

} // end of the module
```

I have removed extra code which is not relevant to this question.

Functions called within route:

**Function followFeed**

```
async function followFeed(toFollowId, userObject, follow) {
    const args = {
        data: {
            follow: {
                class: "user",
                id: toFollowId
            }
        },
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Cookie": JWT_COOKIE_NAME + "=" + jwt.sign(userObject, SECRET, {
                expiresIn: TOKENTIME
            })
        }
    }
    if (follow) {
        return rest.post(FEED_API + '/follow', args)
    }
    return rest.post(FEED_API + '/unfollow', args)
}
```

**Function follow**

```
 follow: function(user_id, followee_type, followee_id) {
        return db("follower").returning("followee_id").insert({ "user_id": user_id, "followee_id": followee_id, "followee_type": followee_type })
            .then(data => {
                return data[0]
            })
    },
```

[image: Request]

Can someone help me and tell me what is wrong with my code?
I am signed in and session has JWT, route exist then why I am getting 404?
What is wrong with code at backend?

In browser console I get:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for
>   URL

This is what I get when I print  `console.log(rest.post(FEED_API + '/follow', args))`

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _progressHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _settledValue: undefined }
Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot POST http://localhost/activity-feed/api/v1/follow
    at Request.<anonymous> (projectpath\node_modules\restling\restling.js:26:21)
```

**Update**

Below is activity feed route:

```
router.post("/v1/follow", function(ctx) {
    const user = ctx.state.user
    const request = ctx.request.body
    return feedRepo.followUserFeed(user.id, request.follow)
        .then(result => {
            ctx.body = result
        })
        .catch(error => {
            ctx.error = error
        })
})
```

Function called inside this route

```
followUserFeed: async function(id, feed) {
    const userFeed = new GSFlatFeed(LOOKUP.FEEDS.USER, id)
    const feedToFollow = new GSFlatFeed(feed.class, feed.id)
    const res = await StreamProvider.followFeed(userFeed, feedToFollow)
    return res
},
```

app.js of activity-feed/api

```
const Koa = require("koa")
const Router = require("koa-router")
const body = require("koa-body")
const cors = require("kcors")
const passport = require("koa-passport")
const logger = require("winston")
var JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy
const CONFIG = require("config")
const SECRET = CONFIG.get("auth.jwt.secret")
const JWT_COOKIE_NAME = CONFIG.get("auth.jwt.cookie.name")

const allRoutes = require("./server/routes/all-routes")

const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router()
const jwtAuth = passport.authenticate(["jwt"], { session: false })

passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
        secretOrKey: SECRET,
        jwtFromRequest: function(req) {
            var token = null
            if (req && req.cookies) {
                token = req.cookies.get(JWT_COOKIE_NAME)
            }
            return token
        }
    },
    function(jwt_payload, done) {
        done(null, jwt_payload)
    }))

router.use("/v1/*", jwtAuth)

allRoutes(router)

app.use(async(ctx, next) => {
    try {
        await next()
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(err)
        ctx.throw(err.status || 500, err.message)
    }
})
app.use(cors())
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(body())
app
    .use(router.routes())
    .use(router.allowedMethods())

module.exports = app
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While registering the routes you have missed the FEED_API (base url).

```
PROTECTED_ROUTES.forEach(url => {
   router.use(url, jwtAuth)
})
```

So your url actually looks like **http://localhost/collab/follow** instead of http://localhost/activity-feed/api/v1/follow

Instead, you should register your routes like,

```
// Protect the marked routes
module.exports = (router) => {
   // Protect the marked routes
   PROTECTED_ROUTES.forEach(url => {
       router.use(FEED_API  + url, jwtAuth)
   })
   // router.use("/collab", jwtAuth)

   router.post(FEED_API + "/collab/follow", async function (ctx) {
```

Now you can POST to /collab/follow as http://localhost/activity-feed/api/v1/collab/follow

Comment: I did not get your point completely, so that means activity-feed/api/v1/follow is not protected url so why it is returning 404 response? If I console log inside route of ativity-feed/v1/follow it does log in terminal then why it do semd response? Can you help me with this please. Thanks for your response!! :)

Comment: while registering you should give the correct handler path. You should prefix all the paths with FEED_API